# Variable counter1 has the null value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working in the node and mongoose.

```
counters.findOneAndUpdate({id: 'doc_id'}, {$inc: { seq: 1} }, function(error, counter1) {
    //
}
```

In this, while creating a record, counter1 is taking null value. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `new` and `upsert` flags into it to tell it to create a new doc if not found and return the update/inserted document. Here is the command you should use:

```
counters.findOneAndUpdate({id: 'doc_id'}, {$inc: { seq: 1} }, {new: true, upsert: true}, function(error, counter1) {
    console.log(counter1);
}
```